# Nullity and rank of the linear transformation $T[f(t)] = \int_a^b f(t) \sin (x-t) dt ~\forall~x \in [a,b]$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real functions continuous on $[a, b]$. If $f\in V, g=T(f)$ means that $$g(x)=\int_a^b f(t)\sin(x-t)\,dt\hspace{1 cm} for\ a\le x\le b$$

Then, the nullity and rank of such a transformation?

**Attempt:** Let $g(x)=0 \implies g(x)$ is the constant function $0 $.

$\implies 0 = \int_a^b f(t)\sin(x-t)\,dt$

Could anyone please tell me how to move forward from here?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The computation of nullity and rank of a linear transformation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917850/the-computation-of-nullity-and-rank-of-a-linear-transformation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something you may try is to change the integral with trigonometric identities: $$\int_a^b f(t)\sin(x-t)dt = \sin(x)\int_a^b f(t)\cos(t)dt - \cos(x)\int_a^b f(t)\sin(t)dt.$$ Then you can find functions for which both integrals are zero. For instance if $a=0$ and $b=2\pi$ (which you can shift and scale your integral to), we have $$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nt)\sin(t)dt = \frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \sin(nt+t)-\sin(nt-t)\right)dt=0$$ as well as $$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nt)\cos(t)dt = 0.$$

Thus $f(t)=\cos(nt)$ for any natural number $n > 1$ would be in the nullspace. The same is true for any function of the form $f(t)=\sin(mt)$ for natural numbers $m > 1$ and also for sums of such functions.

Comment: There are more functions that will make this zero. These are a few examples.

Comment: Note also that $f$ is in the nullspace of the operator iff both of these integrals are zero. This is because $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) . I have a question please. So, it's clear from above that there are infinite functions which satisfy the nullity. So, when there are infinite elements in a subspace, there must be an infinite basis as well. Is this a correct way to infer that dimension of null space is infinite? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes the nullspace has infinite dimension. In particular you can describe them in terms of their Fourier series.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Comment: Note also you can see after the expansion of the sine term that any result of the operator will be a weighted sum of sine and cosine. Thus the rank is 2 and the nullity is infinite

Comment: Do you mean that in the expansion of $$\int_a^b f(t)\sin(x-t)dt = \sin(x)\int_a^b f(t)\cos(t)dt - \cos(x)\int_a^b f(t)\sin(t)dt.$$, we expand both $\sin$ and $\cos$ on the right?

Comment: Since $\int_a^b f(t)\cos(t)$ and $\int_a^b f(t)\sin(t)$ are scalar values, this means the result of the operation yields a function of the form $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$. I.e. the range is the span of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, and thus the operator is rank 2. From this you can conclude that the nullity is infinite.

Comment: I think that a and b should be constants.